# Confused by python package scoping

Tags: python, package

I'm new to python, and confused by certain behavior.

I have a directory called `d`.  In this directory, I have two files:

`__init__.py`:

```
from d import *
```

and

`d.py`:

```
var = None

def printVar():
  global var
  print "from d: var=%s" % `var`
```

From the directory above `d`, I get this interaction within python:

```
>>> import d
>>> d.var = 5
>>> d.printVar()
from d: var=None
```

Why is `var` not changed from the perspective of `d.py`?

My real goal is to accomplish the following:

- Keep `__init__.py` small
- Be able to change a `d.py`-global variable

If it makes a difference, I have multiple files in my package directory, and it would be sub-optimal to combine these into a single file.

What is an acceptable way to do that?

Comment: On a side note, something about Python best practices...  Avoid using the `*` import if you can. Having more than one of those is a module can cause problems. Don't put anything in the `__init__.py` file. Just use the `from d import X` style. Don't change global variables in a module from something outside the module. Use a class to contain state like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
import d
```

you're importing the package, not the module.

Just import the module d within the package:

```
>>> from d import d
>>> d.var = 5
>>> d.printVar()
from d: var=5
```

Comment: To clarify: in the original code, `d.var = 5` rebinds the `var` attribute of the `d` **package** to 5 (it had been bound to `None` by the `from d import *` in `__init__.py`), but leaves the `var` attribute of the `d` **module** untouched. Calling `d.printVar()` accesses `printVar` from the package, which happens to alias the function that's found in the module, which uses the module's `var` attribute. If `var` had been initialized to `[]` and we did `d.var.append('foo')` instead, then it would have "worked", since we would be mutating a mutable value instead of rebinding the variable.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll add a setVar() function to d.py to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual name of the global `var` should be `d.d.var` (because it is in module `d` in package `d`)

So you could

1) Just refer to it as `d.d.var` when you set it

2) Make a setter in `d.py`

Unfortunately these probably won't work:

a) Copy it into `d.var` and try and set it there (what you have in your question) -- it's a different variable

a) import it back like `from __init__ import var` (recursive imports)

Answer (score 0):

```
from X import *
```

Copies all of the names from X into the local module. As a result, modifying the local module won't modify the original.

As for what you actually want to do, you could use some python hackery and replace the module object with one of your own which overloads the operation of assigning an attribute. But don't do that. That'll require a lot of code and just make you look odd.

I suggest having a function that the foo's client code can call.